# Problem related to remainder theorem

Tags: calculus

I want to show that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, all the coefficients of $R(x)$ are even where $x^{7n}+1=(x^3+x+1)Q(x)+R(x)$. Any ideas? ($Q(x),R(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and the degree of $R(x)$ is at most 2).

Comment: Presumably, you also want $R$ to have degree at most $2$?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I will edit my question

Comment: Do the $n=1$ case by polynomial division and then use induction on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

We remark that $$x^7+1\equiv (x + 1) (x^3 + x + 1) (x^3 + x^2 + 1) \pmod 2$$ so the claim is true for $n=1$.

Working $\pmod 2$, we note that the roots of $x^{7n}+1$ are precisely the $7n-$roots of unity over the field of order $2$.  Of course the $7-$roots of unity are a subset of those, hence $x^{7n}+1$ is divisible by $x^7+1\pmod 2$.  But $x^3+x+1$ divides $x^7+1\pmod 2$ so we are done.

Comment: Why there are $7n$-roots of unity over $F_2$?

Comment: There are $7n-$roots of unity over every field.  By "over" I don't mean that the roots are $\textit {in}$ the field of order $2$; rather, they are in an extension of that field.  Or, if you prefer, in the algebraic closure of that field.

Comment: Oh, got it thanks